# Peculiar issue with ping

Tags: ubuntu, ping

I'm using `ping` from package `iputils-ping` (`3:20121221-4ubuntu1.1`) on Ubuntu 14.04.

When pinging a host `host2.lan` with IP `192.168.1.20` that is down initially but comes up during the run of `ping`, I see this when `host2.lan` comes online (between sequence number 56 and 57):

```
From host1.lan (192.168.1.1) icmp_seq=49 Destination Host Unreachable
From host1.lan (192.168.1.1) icmp_seq=50 Destination Host Unreachable
From host1.lan (192.168.1.1) icmp_seq=51 Destination Host Unreachable
From host1.lan (192.168.1.1) icmp_seq=52 Destination Host Unreachable
From host1.lan (192.168.1.1) icmp_seq=53 Destination Host Unreachable
From host1.lan (192.168.1.1) icmp_seq=54 Destination Host Unreachable
From host1.lan (192.168.1.1) icmp_seq=55 Destination Host Unreachable
From host1.lan (192.168.1.1) icmp_seq=56 Destination Host Unreachable
64 bytes from host1.lan (192.168.1.1): icmp_seq=57 ttl=64 time=0.303 ms
64 bytes from host1.lan (192.168.1.1): icmp_seq=58 ttl=64 time=0.165 ms
64 bytes from host1.lan (192.168.1.1): icmp_seq=60 ttl=64 time=0.284 ms
64 bytes from host1.lan (192.168.1.1): icmp_seq=61 ttl=64 time=0.181 ms
64 bytes from host1.lan (192.168.1.1): icmp_seq=62 ttl=64 time=0.136 ms
64 bytes from host1.lan (192.168.1.1): icmp_seq=63 ttl=64 time=0.180 ms
```

What's going on here? Am I receiving an echo from `host1.lan` here or from `host2.lan` and it just gets shown as `host1.lan` erroneously?

---

Description for search engines: pinging offline `host2` from `host1` yields `Destination Host Unreachable` initially, but switches to an echo reply from `host1` as soon as host2 comes up.

Comment: Could you do "route -n" please

Comment: Can you log into `host2.lan` and trace traffic from its point of view? Can you reach it with protocols other than ping? Are you absolutely completely sure that this can in no way be an IP address conflict? If so, what makes you believe it can't be one?

Comment: @Gilles: I don't know how I would do that. I noticed this during a reboot of host2 and the only way I could synthesize a similar behavior is `ifdown`, I reckon. Need to see what I have in OpenWRT. Will tell tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplified:

1. your host sends `ARP` requests for "who has `host2.lan`";
2. when it doesn't receive any response, it sends an "`echo-request` for `host2.lan`" to its gateway (presumably `host1.lan`);
3. the gateway answers with a `host-unreachable`;
4. when `host2.lan` wakes up it replies to the `ARP` requests, and gets registered in the `ARP` tables on all machines in your LAN;
5. your host then starts sending the `icmp-echo` packets to `host2.lan` instead of sending them to the gateway;
6. the gateway stops replying with `host-unreachable` and forwards the few `icmp-echo` it has still has in transit to the (now known by `ARP`) `host2.lan`;
7. finally, `host2.lan` replies with `echo-reply`.

By the way, this is exactly what is supposed to happen.  It isn't specific to Linux in any way.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to check this tomorrow. This sounds like a very logical explanation for the situation I encounter.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt ping is printing the wrong IP address—I'm pretty sure it'll print what's actually in the packet. I'd suggest tcpdump/wireshark to investigate further. Things that come to mind:

- Firewall NAT rules. On both the machine you're pinging from, the machine you're pinging, and (especially if its a hop between you and to host2!) host1.
- DNS confusion. Your DNS entries are wrong, and you're not pinging what you think you are. Or your reverse entries are wrong.
- IP conflict (does the other host have the wrong IP?)

It does appear to have come from a remote host, guessing by the timestamps. Here 0.1 ms is remote over gig-e, 0.02 ms is local.

Comment: Option 2 is not possible, since the lookup of the name when I invoke `ping host2.lan` *proves* that DNS works fine (similarly `getent hosts`). If I cancel `ping` and re-run the exact same command *after* `host2.lan` comes online, it will work just fine. This kind of rules out number 3. Both are on the same network segment and make no use of NAT in their local netfilter tables (both are Linux hosts, one Ubuntu the other OpenWRT).